# How to show the image on the application form in PyQt

Tags: ros, pyqt, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want add camera view from topic "camera/image_raw" in PyQt application like art_teleop.py (http://www.ros.org/wiki/art_teleop).
How to do it? Are there any examples?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28512/how-to-show-the-image-on-the-application-form-in-pyqt/) by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 641 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2012-02-26**:
Thank you, but I need exactly Qt image displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can easily see from that script how to subscribe to "camera/image_raw", but I don't know enough about Qt image displaying to tell you the next step.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0